# On select date propagating to previous month.(react-datepicker)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker 3.1.3 version, I am trying to show the previous month and present months using monthsShown and showPreviousMonths, for monthsShown = 1 it is working fine but for monthsShown > 1 on the selected date, it is propagating to previous months.

```
<DatePicker
   shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
   selectsRange
   monthsShown={2}
   showPreviousMonths={true}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official [link](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-show-previous-months), I think some issue with setting-up your `startDate`.

```
    () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      showPreviousMonths
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      monthsShown={2}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: even here if I am clicking on the date, it is not staying on the same month

Comment: Getting same issue. The month keeps changing when selecting a date range.